# Auto_open & Workbook_open with Connection refresh in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a script that refreshes my data connection to a SQL server. I need to the macro to run when the workbook is opened but for some reason it will not. I guess it has to do with the connection refresh.  I tried with both Workbook_Open and Auto_Open() and neither are working. Other than the data load the only thing I am doing is filtering and copying data, nothing exotic.

Does the data refresh need permissions outside of the script, is that the problem?

Here are the first couples lines.

`Sub Auto_Open()
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection Name").Refresh
other stuff
end sub`

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the code in 'ThisWorkbook' object, right.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
     ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'Step 1: Use the RefreshAll method
    Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).RefreshAll
End Sub
```

Comment: It is in that sheet, does it need to be in a module for the workbook?

Answer (score 0):

user6058587 was close, but you just need to add this to ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
'Step 1: Use the RefreshAll method
    Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name).RefreshAll
End Sub
```